# How can I handle disconnect event using graphql-subscriptions

Tags: websocket, graphql, nestjs, graphql-subscriptions

I am using `graphql-subscriptions` to manage session (rooms).

I have simple application like "chat".

I can send message to chat using:

```
import { PubSub } from 'graphql-subscriptions';
...

pubSub.publish(triggerName, payload)
```

I can listen to subscription events..

But I don't know how to properly handle when user left to room (for example closing full browser)...

Is there any "disconnect" event?

I am using `nestjs` server and `react` with `apollo-link-ws`

Thank you all.

Comment: +1 I really want to know how to handle this in a Nestful way. The closest I've come is to add the subscriptions property to the GraphqlModule. There you have an onDisconnect event but I have no idea how ti dispatch it to resolvers/services

Comment: dispatching to resolvers/services is fairly easy using some state management or rxjs